# OpenSSL missing BIO_do_connect in libeay32.dll

Tags: windows, dll, openssl

I'm introducing myself into OpenSSL programming, using OpenSSL dll external libraries (ssleay32.dll and libeay32.dll).
Trying to establish simple socket connection, I got stuck with BIO_do_connect function, which is obviously missing in libeay32.dll. Maybe some other functions are missing there, compared with static libs.

Does anybody know how to use then these libraries? All infos I found in internet concern the static libs, which obviously don't miss any of desired functions.

Answer (score 1):

`BIO_do_connect` is not a function at all - it is a macro. Ultimately this causes the `BIO_ctrl` function to be called which should be present in both static and dynamic libraries.

Comment: Thanks for advice. Now I'm aware of it. Souce code inspection is helpful to find all the defines.